# where is the syntax error in this Django QuerySet sort?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, syntax-error, models

I'm getting a syntax error on this line of code, which references models of the type which follows.

**views.py**

```
    unordered_group = Unordered_Group(count=group.same_count, group=group_model)
    unordered_group.save()
ordered_groups = Unordered_Group.objects.all().order_by('count')  # SYNTAX ERROR
```

**models.py**

```
class Unordered_Group(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)
```

I don't think I made any typos, so can anyone tell me what's wrong with the syntax?  Thanks for any help!

edit: traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  90.                 response = middleware_method(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\common.py" in process_request
  72.                     urlresolvers.is_valid_path("%s/" % request.path_info, urlconf)):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  573.         resolve(path, urlconf)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  453.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  222.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  96.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /associate
Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 53)
```

Comment: Please paste the entire traceback.

Comment: I don't see any typos. trace might help

Comment: @bnjmn khalid posting the traceback now in edit...

Comment: What is the line _before_ the line 53 in your `views.py`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid    posted traceback, thanks.

Comment: @RedBaron  posted the two preceding lines of code

Comment: @DavidJ., Need more lines.

Comment: This could be a tab/space mismatch. In your editor find the function that replaces all tabs with spaces, execute it, save the file, and then see if the error happens again.

Answer (score 2):

There's no syntax error in the given code.

Check lines before the given line.

For example, the following code

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

print(add(a,b)
c = 1 + 2
```

yields following error (The `print ..` line is missing `)`, but it report syntax error at next line)

```
  File "t.py", line 5
    c = 1 + 2
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```